# Magento 1.9 items go out of stock suddenly after a certain amount of time - For no good reason

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, inventory, stock

I've posted this question on [magento.stackexchange.com](http://magento.stackexchange.com) but got no response due to lower traffic there than here... So here it is...

> I'm working on a website for a client and right before publishing the
>   website, I noticed that all the products went out of stock itself. So
>   I put them all back in stock and everything looked fine, but when I
>   checked back after a few hours all the products were back out of
>   stock.
>
> I tried a few times to re-enter the stock quantities, re-index and
>   clear the cache, but I'm still having this weird issue - everything
>   looks fine until like 2-3 hours later everything goes out of stock.
>
> Any suggestion what could be causing this issue?
>
> Thanks in advance!

PS. I didn't share the code because I would have to share the code of the entire website...

Comment: Does the client need the website to keep track of stock?

Comment: Check third party extension or script that may be run based on cron setting.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. This does belong on http://magento.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Enigmativity Absolutely FALSE, This Is a programming question - I just don't know where to look for the code that is causing this.

Comment: @martinschwartz - What is the programming question you're asking?

Comment: @Enigmativity Which code could cause this to happen

Answer (score 0):

> Any suggestion what could be causing this issue?

Any imaginable 3rd party application or module that has access to cataloginventory model or its tables in database.

**Suggestion how to debug this:**

put this snippet into inventory observer
app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Observer.php
somewhere at the begin of **saveInventoryData** method. *(Or create local module and observe a save event)*

```php
Mage::log(Varien_Debug::backtrace(true, true), null, 'inventory.log');
```

after you reproduce the behaviour just check the log file under <*doc root*>/var/log/inventory.log